# CTE combine with a LIKE statemnet

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue.
This is a part of my code:

```
case when ( EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM CTE WHERE UPPER(s.[Contents Total]) LIKE UPPER('%' + CTE.Contents + '%'))) Then 'depot' ELSE '-' end as Content_Search_XXX
```

I do not know how to adjust this part `LIKE UPPER('%' + CTE.Contents + '%')`.
Because when in the column `Contents Total` is found something like this:

> Depot Service AUG 2018

or

> Mexico Service Depot cancelled

then it works fine. The query sets the *depot* record into the column `Content_Search_XXX`.

But when the expression 'depot' is in the end, e.g.:

> July 2018 Services for XYZ study depot

then the query ignores it, and did not set the *depot* record into the column `Content_Search_XXX`.

Please is there anyone who could advise me, and tell me what I have done wrong?

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: try LIKE '%' + UPPER(CTE.Contents) + '%'

Comment: Unfortunately, the same issue lasts...but anyway thanks for your tip...

Comment: Check if `CTE.Contents` has trailing spaces: `LIKE UPPER('%' + RTRIM(CTE.Contents) + '%'))) `

Comment: @dnoeth - this works perfect! Thank you very much for your help! Great! :)

Comment: You should try to fix the source data, trailing spaces are really bad (or maybe the column is defined as CHAR instead of VarChar). Of course, *leading* spaces are even worse :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
CASE WHEN
EXISTS (
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM CTE
WHERE CHARINDEX(TRIM(CTE.Contents), s.[Contents Total] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) > 0)
THEN 'depot'
ELSE '-'
END
AS Content_Search_XXX
```